# what is the time complexity of the algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

It is a problem from an algorithm textbook, i think the time complexity is log(n!), but my classmate says it is nlog(n). Thanks very much for you reply!!

```
count ← 0
for i ← 1 to n do
    j ← ⌊n/2⌋
    while j ≥ 1 do
        count ← count + 1
        if j is odd then
           j←0
        else
           j ← j/2
        end if
    end while
 end for
```

Comment: Worst case is O(n log n), when n is power of 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think the time complexity is `log(n!)`, but my classmate says it is `nlog(n)`.

You're both right. As can be seen from [Stirling's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation),

```
log n! = n * log n - n +O(log(n)),
```

(`log` is the natural logarithm here) more precisely:

```
log n! = (n + 1/2) * log n - n + 1/2 * log (2π) + O(1/n)
```

so `O(log n!)` and `O(n*log n)` are the same class.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the worst case, n = 2<sup>p</sup>

- loop 1 to n
- for each loop, divide *j* by 2 until it is < 1

So, `n * log`<sub>2</sub>`(n)` iterations, or time complexity of `O(n log(n))`

--

(As per comment, the log base is not necessary in complexity, as *log<sub>2</sub>(x)* is actually *log(x)/log(2)* i.e. *log(x) multiplied by constant*)